# arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") not working in sub thread

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, python-addin, multithreading

I want to create a customize tool in ArcMap by Python Add-in wizards.I found that arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") does not work in the sub thread.

How can I call main thread to execute arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") in the sub thread?

I can't use arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") in the main thread directly because socket receive function using while True loop will make ArcMap hang.

```
 import arcpy
 import socket
 import threading
 import pythonaddins
 from win32api import ShellExecute

class ButtonClass1(object):
"""Implementation for power_line_planning_addin_addin.button (Button)"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):


       def execute_socket():


          def client():
          # create a GUI contained socket client in path_finding_ui.py
             python_exe_path = "../python.exe"
             py_path = "path_finding_ui.py"
             ShellExecute(0, "open", python_exe_path, py_path, "", 0)


          def server():
          # create a socket server
             tcpserver = socket.socket()
             host = socket.gethostname()
             port = 12321
             tcpserver.bind((host, port))
             tcpserver.listen(1)

             while True:
             # when receive msg from client,highlight the polyline according to the field
                conn, addr = tcpserver.accept()
                data = conn.recv(1024)

             # unfortuanately, arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") not working in the sub thread
                sql_statement = "[PLANNING_POWER_LINE_ID] = \'%s\'" % data
                mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
                layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
                for lyr in layers:
                     if lyr.name.encode("utf-8") == "plan project":
                         arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", sql_statement)
                         arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
                         arcpy.RefreshTOC()
                del mxd

        
          def thread_active():
             thread1 = threading.Thread(target=server)
             thread2 = threading.Thread(target=client)

             threads_list = []
             threads_list.append(thread2)
             threads_list.append(thread1)

             for i in threads_list:
                 i.start()

          thread_active()
     execute_socket()
```

Comment: I'm in no way an expert in multithreading but I've always understood the python addin was about creating alternate methods for interacting with main main GUI of ArcMap. So typically code is linked to an on button\tool event like clicking on a map. How is your code being run? Is it hooking into the application extension event? I don't know if creating threads is like spawn a whole new process which has no link back to the live mxd? I've used the multiprocessing module without issues but may be thats not compatible with your workflow?

Comment: @Hornbydd  it's a button event,that's why I can't use while True loop in the main thread, it will make ArcMap collapse.

Comment: Ah may be its as simple as having a break out in your code? You enter the While True loop but you have no scenario that allows you to break out of the loop. I'm assuming once you have applied your selection that's when you want to break out of the infinite loop?

Comment: @Hornbydd the loop is used to receive message from socket client in the tkinter GUI, when user clicks  combobox and  selects a value in the tkinter GUI, the socket server will receive the value,and then highlight the polyline selected in the tkinter by user. So, I think the loop can't be closed when the user interact with the tkinter GUI.

Comment: I don't know enough about multi-threading but it sounds like a "chicken and egg" situation to me. You have a tkinter GUI that they are interacting with (how was that initiated?)  but your code you have shown is fired off by a python addin button onclick event which puts itself into an infinite loop with no way of seemingly breaking out. If this was me I would be rethinking the user workflow and how they are interacting with external applications.